Flexbox layout without item re-rendering to new parent
This is the layout i'm trying to make:

I have a difficult flexbox layout that I'm trying to achieve, and I have a difficult restriction that one of the items is a Webgl player and cannot be conditionally rendered because that would restart the WebGl player. All of the items should be able to occupy item 1 position when clicked on. How would you code this flex layout knowing that item 2 can only change its order, not its parent.
I've tried making item 2 absolutely positioned though that is less than ideal.

Use a grid layout and arbitrarily place the items at fixed positions regardless of DOM order

Maybe share code of what you have, with more details on the webGl player

Here's an example of accomplishing your design goals using css grid


const get = query => [...document.querySelectorAll(query)];

get("section").forEach(el => 
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const isTwo = el.classList.contains("two");
    const isThree = el.classList.contains("three");
    const isFour = el.classList.contains("four");
    const isFive = el.classList.contains("five");
    const currentOne = get(".one")[0];
    if (isTwo) {
      el.classList.remove("two");
      currentOne.classList.add("two");
    }
    if (isThree) {
      el.classList.remove("three");
      currentOne.classList.add("three");
    }
    if (isFour) {
      el.classList.remove("four");
      currentOne.classList.add("four");
    }
    if (isFive) {
      el.classList.remove("five");
      currentOne.classList.add("five");
    }
    currentOne.classList.remove("one");
    el.classList.add("one");
  })
);
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  grid-column: span 2;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 18pt;
  transition: font-size 200ms;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: var(--color);
  order: var(--order);
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.one {
  grid-column: span 4;
  grid-row: span 3;
  cursor: unset;
}

.four, .five {
  grid-column: span 1;
}

section:hover {
  font-size: 30pt;
}

.one { 
  --order: 1;
}
.two { 
  --order: 2;
}
.three { 
  --order: 3;
}
.four { 
  --order: 4;
}
.five { 
  --order: 5;
}

.red {
  --color: red;
}

.blue {
  --color: blue;
}

.green {
  --color: green;
}

.yellow {
  --color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

.purple {
  --color: purple;
}
<section class="one red">1</section>
<section class="two blue">2</section>
<section class="three green">3</section>
<section class="four yellow">4</section>
<section class="five purple">5</section>



